# Not able to add feature class layer into new Map Viewer, ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-class, feature-layer

Using ArcGIS Online

When in New Map Viewer, feature class layers that I have saved in My Content do not appear when I search the Browse layers through the Add tab. Only KML files are showing in the Content search. Also, when viewing the feature layers in My Content page I only have the option of opening them in Map Viewer Classic.

The only way I get them in the new Map Viewer is to open them in Classic, save a map, and then open the map in New Map Viewer. Switching the map over to New Map Viewer, I am able to view properties of the feature layers but I cannot change style, add labels, or configure pop-ups (the tabs are grayed out). I would like to import them directly into New Map Viewer and modify them.

Screen shot of the New Map Viewer, Add tab > Browse layers > My Content :

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the add data option in map viewer? Open the map viewer from the item details page of the layer.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the (import) data tab in New Map viewer. Wondering if you are able to add feature layers this way, or if perhaps this is a feature not yet available for new map viewer?